# Highcharts buttons with different menuitems not working

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create 2 export buttons (share & download) with two different menuItems in HighCharts

- Button 1 (Share)

  - MenuItem 1: Share on Facebook
  - MenuItem 2: Share on Twitter
- Button 2) Download

  - MenuItem 1: Print
  - MenuItem 2: Download as PNG

As you can see on http://jsfiddle.net/kmPh8/18/

```
exporting: {
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Download',
            x: -82,
            symbolFill: '#B5C9DF',
            hoverSymbolFill: 'red',
            menuItems: [
                {
                    text: 'Print',
                    onclick: function() {
                        alert('blue menu 1');
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Download as PNG',
                    onclick: function() {
                        alert('blue menu10000');
                    }
                }
           ]
      },
    {
        text: 'Share',
        x: -10,
        symbolFill: '#B5C9DF',
        hoverSymbolFill: 'blue',
        menuItems: [{
            text: 'Share on facebook',
            onclick: function() {
                alert('Facebook Share');
            }},
        {
            text: 'Share on twitter',
            onclick: function() {
                alert('Twitter share');
            }}
                        ]}]
}
```

But... the problem is whatever button you click first you will see the menuItems on the second button, if you 'run' it again click the other button you will see the problem again. Each button basically doesn't show the individual menuitems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i think this is fixed now. the fiddle works.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it looks like a problem, because I've tried to reproduce it here
http://jsfiddle.net/MzB9b/2/ and indeed issue is displayed.

```
 exporting: {
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
                menuItems: [{
                    text: 'Export to PNG (small)',
                    onclick: function() {
                        alert('EXPORT PNG small');
                    }
                }, {
                    text: 'Export to PNG (large)',
                    onclick: function() {
                        alert('EXPORT PNG large');
                    },
                    separator: false
                }]
            },
            testButton: {
                symbol: 'diamond',
                x: -62,
                symbolFill: '#B5C9DF',
                hoverSymbolFill: '#779ABF',
                _titleKey: 'printButtonTitle',
                 menuItems: [{
                    text: 'Facebook',
                    onclick: function() {
                        alert('Facebook');
                    },
                }, {
                    text: 'Twitter',
                    onclick: function() {
                        alert('Twitter');
                    },
                    separator: false
                }]
            }
        }
    }
```

So I reported this problem to the developers https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1908